# Reasonphrase is always empty after changing http1:1 to http 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, webapi, http2

After we changed http1 to http2 we are not getting `reasonphrase` from the api `filter`

we are assigning `reasonphrase` like below in our api `filter`

```
actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage()
{
    ReasonPhrase = "Error",
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
    Content = new StringContent("Token is not assigned to the logged in user")
};
```

we are getting `ReasonPhrase` as empty in our front end(`jQuery Ajax function`)

```
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, code, ReasonPhrase) { //code// }
```

what can I do to prevent this? or what should I use instead of `reasonphrase`.

**NOTE**

we have multiple `ReasonPhrase` with same `StatusCode` and hence we can't use `StatusCode`.